# Make recurring reminders automatically be bundled

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Is it possible to make a recurring reminder to always be bundled in some category by default, e.g. "Take out the garbage" every Monday morning automatically bundled to the "Home" bundle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019.